# Hide "Logged on", "# programs running" on WinXP Fast User Switching

Tags: windows, fast-user-switching

When Fast User Switching is activated on a Windows XP machine, it returns the user to the Welcome Screen and allows logging on to a different account. Any active users have either **"# of programs running"** or **"Logged on"** displayed under their username.

Is there any way to remove or edit these messages? I know its possible to create custom Welcome Screens, but is there any less drastic measure that don't involve custom screens?

Answers involving hex-editors are welcome.

Comment: Are you saying patching `logonui` with a hex-editor is _less_ drastic than patching `logonui` with a specially designed tool to modify the Welcome Screen?

Comment: ...then use the customization tools to modify the _current_ Welcome Screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use software such as [Stardock Logon Studio](http://www.stardock.com/products/logonstudio/) to customize the logon screen. You don't need to change it entirely – just delete the two links.

---

To do it manually, use a Win32 [resource editor](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=resource+editor) such as [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/) or [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm) to edit resource `UIFILE:1000:1033` (type `UIFILE`, ID `1000`, lang `1033`) of file `%SystemRoot%\System32\logonui.exe`.

The part you'll have to edit/remove is lines 939 to 940:

```
            <button id=atom(status0) class="status" layoutpos=none/>
            <button id=atom(status1) class="status" layoutpos=none/>
```

The element with `id=atom(status0)` displays *%d unread mail messages*, and `id=atom(status1)` is for *%d programs running*.

Comment: FWIW, Logon Studio might even be _safer_ than a resource editing tool.

Answer (score 1):

Disallow `SYSTEM` from reading the `HKCU\SessionInformation` registry key.

1. Open `regedit`
2. Expand *My Computer → `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`*
3. Right-click on the *`SessionInformation`* key, choose *Permissions...*
4. In the name list, select the *SYSTEM* entry
5. Under *Permissions for SYSTEM*, check the Deny box for *Read*.
6. Click *OK*.

[image: (Screenshot)]

You will have to do this separately for each user's registry. Also, I am not sure if these changes will persist after logoff :(

Comment: You might be able to create a program that would change the permissions on startup. (What is the problem with showing "Logged in", anyway?)