# Hide "Logged on", "# programs running" on Windows 7 Fast User Switching

Tags: windows-7, fast-user-switching

I want to do the exact same thing that this question did in Windows XP:

> [Hide "Logged on", "# programs running" on WinXP Fast User Switching](https://superuser.com/questions/265832/hide-logged-on-programs-running-on-winxp-fast-user-switching)

However, I want to do it in Windows 7. I attempted to do it the same way they did it, but the filepaths were different.